# Android - app not showing

Tags: android, android-studio

I am developing an application on android. When I run the app from Android Studio, it opens automatically and I can play but the app has no icon in my phone. I can find it in my storage settings as app installed buy no way to find it on my phone.
I sent it to a friend with a different phone and he had the same problem.

Anyone knows what is happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're most likely missing the correct action/category -- see the link above. Those are magic names that are used to identify activities that should be shown in the launcher/home screen.

Comment: If the link does not help, please update your question with at least the manifest file